# SQL: Calculating Group Rates Between Ranges

Tags: sql

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have a table that contains information on a set of people over different years, if they have a disease, which country they are from and how many cars they have.

The dataset (my_table) looks like this:

```
   year disease country cars
1  2010     yes      uk    8
2  2010     yes      uk    2
3  2010     yes     usa   10
4  2010      no     usa    5
5  2010     yes     usa    4
6  2010      no      uk    6
7  2010      no  canada    7
8  2010      no  canada    5
9  2010     yes  canada    2
10 2010     yes      uk    9
11 2010      no  canada    1
12 2010      no     usa    7
13 2010      no      uk    8
14 2010     yes  canada    3
15 2010      no     usa    1
```

**My Question:**

- I am trying to create groups for the number of cars (e.g. between 0 and 5,5 and 10,10 and 15, greater than 15)
- Then, within each of these ranges, I want to find the percent of people from each country  that have a disease

The final result should be in this format:

```
  brackets country number_of_people_with_disease total_number_of_people   disease_rate
1 0-5 cars     usa                            13                     41           0.31
2 0-5 cars     usa                            19                     45           0.42
```

Here is my attempt to write the query:

```
with brackets as
( select year,
case
when cars > 0 and cars <5 then '0-5 cars'
when cars >= 5 and cars <10 then '5-10 cars'
when cars >= 10 and cars <15 then '10-15 cars'
else 'more than 15 cars'
end as brackets,
country,
disease
from my_table),
rate as
(select year,
brackets,
country,
sum(case when disease = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) as number_of_people_with_disease,
count(*) as total_number_of_people
from brackets
group by year, brackets, country
)
select year, brackets, country, number_of_people_with_disease, total_number_of_people,
round(number_of_people_with_disease * 1.0 / total_number_of_people, 2) as disease_rate
from rate
order by year, brackets;
```

The results look something like this:

```
    year   brackets country number_of_people_with_disease total_number_of_people disease_rate
1   2010   0-5 cars      uk                            11                     12         0.92
2   2010   0-5 cars     usa                             7                     14         0.50
3   2010   0-5 cars  canada                             7                     14         0.50
```

Can someone please tell me if my logic is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: *Can someone please tell me if my logic is correct?* - does your query produce the expected results? Your set labels should be 0-4, 5-9, 10-14.

Answer (score 0):

The query below stores the car number ranges in a `cte` and then `left join`s `my_table` onto the ranges, aggregating the results:

```
with r(l, u) as (
   select 0, 5
   union all
   select 5, 10
   union all
   select 10, 15
   union all
   select 15, null
)
select t1.year, t.s brackets, t1.country, sum(t1.disease = 'yes') number_of_people_with_disease, 
      count(*) total_number_of_people, sum(t1.disease = 'yes')/count(*) disease_rate 
from (select *, concat(l, '-', coalesce(u, '')) s from r) t
left join my_table t1 on t.l <= t1.cars and t1.cars < coalesce(t.u, t1.cars + 1)
group by t1.year, t.s, t1.country
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1KngHI6g)